# JAVASCRIPT Incrementing innerHTML number onmouseover and back to 0 onmouseout

Tags: javascript, rotation, hover, innerhtml, onmouseover

I can't seem to find a solution anywhere.. Basically I have a meter gauge with a needle which when hovered on, rotates. That I got working fine with CSS, though if anyone can guide me on how to do it in Javascript I appreciate.

Most importantly, I need the **number to go up** ( like a car gauge ) onmouseover and back down onmouseout using innerHTML. So how do I make use of a range of numbers in Javascript? I need it to go from 0 to 270.

Thanks in advance :)

HTML:

```
<div id="all">
<svg viewBox="0 0 113 111">
  <style>
    .st3{fill:#17ceff}.st4{fill:none}
  </style>

  <path d="M64.2 56.3c0 4.4-3.6 8-8 8-1.4 0-2.7-.4-3.9-1L31.7 80.6l17.5-20.5c-.6-1.1-1-2.4-1-3.8 0-4.4 3.6-8 8-8s8 3.5 8 8z" fill="#252626" stroke="#fff" stroke-width=".47" stroke-miterlimit="10" id="needle"/>

  <div class="result" id="result">0</div>
</svg>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 #needle {
      transform-origin: inherit;
     transition: 0.70s;
 }

#needle:hover {
    transition: 0.70s;
    transform: rotate(270deg);
}
```

Comment: Can you share the solution that got you close?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="whole-container">
        <div class="meter">0</div>
        <div class="needle"></div>
    </div>
```

**Jquery**

```
    var inte;
    $('.whole-container').on('mouseover', function () {
        clearInterval(inte);
        var i = parseInt($('.meter').text());
        inte = setInterval(() => {
            $('.meter').text(i);
            $('.needle').css('transform', 'rotate(' + i + 'deg)');
            if (i == 270) clearInterval(inte);
            i++;
        }, 100);
    });
    $('.whole-container').on('mouseout', function () {
        clearInterval(inte);
        var i = parseInt($('.meter').text());
        inte = setInterval(() => {
            $('.meter').text(i);
            $('.needle').css('transform', 'rotate(' + i + 'deg)');
            if (i == 0) clearInterval(inte);
            i--;
        }, 100);
    });
```

Please make changes to html and script classes/id as needed

Comment: Hey Shakti, thanks for your reply. Although I can't seem to work around it. My code includes SVG and I need to find a way to combine it with your code. I edited my quesiton so you can see my HTML with the needle done with SVG code. Appreciate further help. Thanks again :)

Comment: ah never mind, I had to connect <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script> to HTML to work. Now though the needle doesn't go up with the number, it rotates sudden when number reaches 270

Comment: OK did it! :D all I needed to change was the CSS: #needle {
  transform-origin: inherit;
}

THANK YOU!